# With Schema Validation enabled on the HTTP Trigger, can I customise the error message returned on failure?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'd like to validate the (JSON) input to a Logic App, which I can do using the Schema Validation option:

[image: Schema Validation option]

Can I customise the error message this sends back? My API design has a particular format for the body of a non-success response that we would like to conform to.

I tried setting a response action immediately after the trigger and specifying "Run After" as Failed but the designer won't allow this.

Comment: Could you implement it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema validation in HTTP trigger couldn't modify the message, so maybe you could don't validate the json data in trigger.

You could use `Parse JSON` action to parse the data to json and validate it. For details you could refer to this blog: [Validating Json Schema in Azure Logic Apps](https://shadabanwer.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/validating-json-schema-in-azure-logic-apps/). The create the response action and set it run after Parse JSON has failed.

You could custom the status code and the response body. I test with `outputs('Parse_JSON')['errors'][0]['message']` it will send the `Parse_JSON` action error message. With this way, you could use parallel branch to create actions after the Parse_JSON success.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is not the ideal solution as I have a trigger with a validation feature that I am not using and instead have to apply a second action and a conditional, which seems like unnecessary work, when it could all just sit in the trigger. But this is good enough.