# Azure Logic App can't display custom error message on required field

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a very simple logic app that accepts a name field (required). In Settings, I set the "Schema Validation" to true and it validates if I send an empty json {}.

The problem is that it displays the default error message of Logic App. I want to custom that message to be more friendly to the user.

Here is my Logic app code:

```
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {},
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
        "manual": {
            "inputs": {
                "schema": {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "message": {
                                "required": "name is required"
                            },
                            "required": true,
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "kind": "Http",
            "operationOptions": "EnableSchemaValidation",
            "type": "Request"
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {}
}
```

I tried to post an empty json by Postman.

This is what I got:

[image]

I expect it to return "name is required" which I set it in Logic App designer.

Please can anyone shed some lights on what goes wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With Schema Validation enabled on the HTTP Trigger, can I customise the error message returned on failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853664/with-schema-validation-enabled-on-the-http-trigger-can-i-customise-the-error-me)

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52909.logic-apps-message-validation-with-xml-json-and-flat-file-schemas-part-2.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Let me look into the 1st link. The 2nd one doesn't seem to be good to me, it's using Function App which looks a bit cumbersome to my architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> message to be more friendly to the user.

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I have followed @George Chen' s [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853664/with-schema-validation-enabled-on-the-http-trigger-can-i-customise-the-error-me) answer:

**Logic app Design:**

[image]

**Logic App Code:**

```
    {
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "message": {
                                    "required": "name is required"
                                },
                                "required": true,
                                "type": [
                                    "null",
                                    "string"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": { },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@outputs('Parse_JSON')['errors'][0]['message']",
                    "statusCode": 400
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": { },
        "parameters": { },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "message": {
                                    "required": "name is required"
                                },
                                "required": true,
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": { }
}
```

Here I kept `runAfter Failed` If the User gives name then you can use a parallel action to follow next process.

**Output:**

[image]

**In Postman:**

[image]

```
Required properties are missing from object: name.
```

And if you provide name in http request, then you can parallelly add another `runAfter Succeeded` after `Parse_Json` and you can follow the next steps of your Workflow of Your Logic App.